# OrderedDict for older versions of python

Tags: python

Ordered dictionaries are extremely useful structures, but unfortunately these are quite recent only working in versions from [3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) and [2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-372-adding-an-ordered-dictionary-to-collections). How can I use an ordered dictionary in older versions?

Comment: Is the orderedDict useful for you? Could you help to check my code at the end of this page

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I installed ordereddict on python 2.6 with pip

```
pip install ordereddict
```

Comment: Could you give me the usage please. I tried easy_install ordereddict and not so sure about the usage.

Comment: from ordereddict import OrderedDict    [Bit of Googling did it]

Comment: PIP on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 22):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), for Python versions 2.4 or later [this code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) should be used. There is also some [code from Raymond Hettinger](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576669/), one of the contributors to the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/). The code here is claimed to work under 2.6 and 3.0 and was made for the proposal.

Comment: The package "ordereddict" implements this for you. As Arthur Ulfeldt pointed out, you can use Pip to install it :)

Comment: @UsAndRufus the ordereddict didn't take effect.

Answer (score 12):

To import a OrderedDict class for different versions of Python, consider this snippet:

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict

# Now use it from any version of Python
mydict = OrderedDict()
```

Versions older than Python 2.6 will need to install `ordereddict` (using pip or other methods), but newer versions will import from the built-in collections module.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could just program your way around it if your situation allows:

```
def doSomething(strInput): return [ord(x) for x in strInput]

things = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

oDict = {}
orderedKeys = []
for thing in things:
    oDict[thing] = doSomething(thing)
    orderedKeys.append(thing)

for key in oDict.keys():
    print key, ": ", oDict[key]

print

for key in orderedKeys:
    print key, ": ", oDict[key]
```

> second :  [115, 101, 99, 111, 110, 100]
>   fourth :  [102, 111, 117, 114, 116, 104]
>   third :  [116, 104, 105, 114, 100]
>   first :  [102, 105, 114, 115, 116]
>
> first :  [102, 105, 114, 115, 116]
>   second :  [115, 101, 99, 111, 110, 100]
>   third :  [116, 104, 105, 114, 100]
>   fourth :  [102, 111, 117, 114, 116, 104]

You could embed the ordered keys in your Dictionary too, I suppose, as oDict['keyList'] = orderedKeys

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try `future`, py2-3 compatible codebase:

1. install `future` via pip:

`pip install future`

2. import and use OrderedDict:

`from future.moves.collections import OrderedDict`

[source](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#collections-counter-and-ordereddict)

Answer (score 0):

in python2.6 gave to me:

```
$ pip install ordereddict
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement from (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for from
```

but

```
$ easy_install ordereddict
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for ordereddict
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ordereddict/
Best match: ordereddict 1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/ordereddict/ordereddict-1.1.tar.gz#md5=a0ed854ee442051b249bfad0f638bbec
Processing ordereddict-1.1.tar.gz
Running ordereddict-1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lYgPE3/ordereddict-1.1/egg-dist-tmp-GF2v6g
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding ordereddict 1.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ordereddict-1.1-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for ordereddict
Finished processing dependencies for ordereddict
```

did.

Answer (score -1):

For those who can't depend on the user having pip for some reason, here is a **really terrible** implementaiton of OrderedDict (it is immutable, has most of the features but none of the performance boost).

```
class OrderedDict(tuple):
    '''A really terrible implementation of OrderedDict (for python < 2.7)'''
    def __new__(cls, constructor, *args):
        items = tuple(constructor)
        values = tuple(n[1] for n in items)
        out = tuple.__new__(cls, (n[0] for n in items))
        out.keys = lambda: out
        out.items = lambda: items
        out.values = lambda: values
        return out

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return next(v for (k, v) in self.items() if k == key)
        except:
            raise KeyError(key)
```