# Dump a dictorary as json with numeric ordered keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
I have a dictonary dumped to json like this
dict({'abc1': {'1': 'asdf', '11': 'asdfasd', "2": 'afds'}, 'abc2': {'1': 'asdf', '11': 'asdfasd', '2': 'afds'}})
```

How can I dump the dictionary to json with ordered keys.
Because of the alphabetic prefix I can't use the following code:

```
import json

d = dict({'2':'two', '11':'eleven'})
json.dumps({int(x):d[x] for x in d.keys()}, sort_keys=True)
```

Can you give me a hint, how to integrate string based keys in the lines?

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this could be relevant for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774361/json-output-sorting-in-python

Comment: JSON doesn't really guarantee order of object properties in any way, and thus any implementation of a JSON en-/decoder is free to disregard order as well. If you depend on the order, objects are the wrong data type to use; use arrays instead with a different way to represent your data.

Comment: What alphabetic prefix are you referring to? Maybe you should clarify what you need by providing sample output

Comment: Example 
`
{
 'abc1': {
  '1': 'asdf',
  '2': 'afds'
  '11': 'asdfasd',

 },
 'abc2': {
  '1': 'asdf',
  '2': 'afds'
  '11': 'asdfasd',
 }
}
`

Comment: There are two broad approaches: 1) ignore the alphabetic portion and just use the number component converted to int using a custom key function for the sort. 2) use natural sorting via natsort or a pyicu collator.

Comment: Third approach use a tuple as the sort key using an alphabetic component and an int component.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand how to sort the keys of a dictionary as *integers* and not in lexigraphical order as strings, because according to that ordering, `'11'` does come before `'2'`.

Consider:

```
>>> d = {'1': 'asdf', '11': 'asdfasd', "2": 'afds'}
>>> {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys(), key=int)}
{'1': 'asdf', '2': 'afds', '11': 'asdfasd'}
```

Fortunately in modern Python (3.6+) dictionaries are insertion ordered, so once this sorting is done, it will remain in the same order.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that they not always integers, see my example...

Comment: @kruemel4 All of the keys in the sub-dictionaries are string representations of integers. At the higher level, the keys "abc1" and "abc2" are ordered lexicographically. You need a better example to show what you mean