# Sort a dictionary- get a LIST not a DICT

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

I am trying to sort a dictionary by its values using sorted(data.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))

I manage to sort the values correctly, but I get a list not a dictionary.

Could sb tell me how to sort my dictionary saving dictionary type?

thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary entries are not ordered. If you want the key-value pairs to be ordered, use a [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Comment: I cannot import that module, i am using python-2.6.1

Comment: @user: [`sudo pip install ordereddict`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617078/ordereddict-for-older-versions-of-python). Also: What's the particular problem you are trying to solve here? Is it about presenting something to the user?

Comment: @user1287285: The link in my answer also points to a drop-in substitute [for Python 2.4 or greater](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/).

Answer (score 0):

As stated before many times, dictionaries can't be sorted.

If you need your dictionary to be sorted for commands such as `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()`, use `sorted(dict.keys())` or `sorted(dict.values())` instead.

If you don't want to do that, the only other option is to use a 2d array, where the format is:

```
((key, value), (key1, value1), (key2, value2), etc.)
```