# Dictionary sorting by key length

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Anyone have any idea how to sort this dictionary by key length?

```
{
    'http://ccc.com/viewvc/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.14'}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}],    
    'http://bbb.com/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.22'}, {'type': 'programming-languages', 'app': 'PHP', 'ver': '5.3.10'}, {'type': 'cms', 'app': 'Drupal', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'javascript-frameworks', 'app': 'jQuery', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'captchas', 'app': 'Mollom', 'ver': None}]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    'http://bbb.com/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.22'}, {'type': 'programming-languages', 'app': 'PHP', 'ver': '5.3.10'}, {'type': 'cms', 'app': 'Drupal', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'javascript-frameworks', 'app': 'jQuery', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'captchas', 'app': 'Mollom', 'ver': None}]
    'http://ccc.com/viewvc/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.14'}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}],    

}
```

I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered; did you want to just display the dictionary? Loop over the keys in a sorted order? Please be specific about your expected output.

Comment: i want to sort the dictionary by key length...not for displaying, for using it further in the application

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

```
newlist = yourdict.items()
sortedlist = sorted(newlist, key=lambda s: len(s[0]))
```

Will give you a new **list** of **tuples** which are sorted by the length of the *original keys*.

Comment: No it wont... `list.sort` is an inplace function and returns `None`. Change it to `sorted(newlist, key=lambda s: len(s[0]))`

Comment: All of the tuples in `newlist` have length 2. You need `key=lambda s: len(s[0])`

Comment: Err I knew I had it like that for a reason. Must be home time! Thanks @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 5):

#### Python v2.7+

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {
    'http://ccc.com/viewvc/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.14'}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}],    
    'http://bbb.com/' : [{'type': 'web-servers', 'app': 'Apache', 'ver': '2.2.22'}, {'type': 'programming-languages', 'app': 'PHP', 'ver': '5.3.10'}, {'type': 'cms', 'app': 'Drupal', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'operating-systems', 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'javascript-frameworks', 'app': 'jQuery', 'ver': None}, {'type': 'captchas', 'app': 'Mollom', 'ver': None}]
}
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[0])))
OrderedDict([('http://bbb.com/', [{'ver': '2.2.22', 'app': 'Apache', 'type': 'web-servers'}, {'ver': '5.3.10', 'app': 'PHP', 'type': 'programming-languages'}, {'ver': None, 'app': 'Drupal', 'type': 'cms'}, {'ver': None, 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'type': 'operating-systems'}, {'ver': None, 'app': 'jQuery', 'type': 'javascript-frameworks'}, {'ver': None, 'app': 'Mollom', 'type': 'captchas'}]), ('http://ccc.com/viewvc/', [{'ver': '2.2.14', 'app': 'Apache', 'type': 'web-servers'}, {'ver': None, 'app': 'Ubuntu', 'type': 'operating-systems'}])])
```

#### Earlier Python versions

See [OrderedDict for older versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617078/ordereddict-for-older-versions-of-python).

Comment: i am using older version of python => 2.6

Comment: @badc0re You can search for 'OrderedDict recipe for Python 2.6'