# Sorting dictionary in python by value in value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Okay so i have this dictionary:

`dict = {'name':{'movie':(actualmovie), 'nreviews': (number)}, ...}`

is there an easy way to order dict by the nreviews value (number) ?

Comment: None of that is a list.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks, i meant dictionary. It's corrected now

Comment: may be [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) can help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Sorting Python Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031482/custom-sorting-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

No, because dicts can't be ordered.

```
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(D.items(), key=(lambda k, v: v['nreviews'])))
```