# How to sort dict using python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have problem about sorting my dict. My code is:

```
x = {('S', 'A'): (5, 8), ('S', 'B'): (11, 17), ('S', 'C'): (8, 14)}

sort_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
print sort_x
sort_x_dict = dict(sort_x)
print sort_x_dict
```

#### Output:

```
[(('S', 'A'): (5, 8)), (('S', 'C'): (8, 14)), (('S', 'B'): (11, 17))]
{('S', 'A'): (5, 8), ('S', 'B'): (11, 17), ('S', 'C'): (8, 14)}
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: `dict` aren't ordered, so sorting them makes no sense. Maybe you want to use `OrederedDict`?

Comment: @Julien They are ordered starting with Python 3.7.

Comment: Prior to Py3.6 `dict`s do retain order so `dict(sort_x)` loses the order of `sort_x`. [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) will keep order.

Comment: @Wen-Ben

my expected is same with `sort_x` : `{('S', 'A'): (5, 8), ('S', 'C'): (8, 14), ('S', 'B'): (11, 17)}`.

Comment: I guess it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031482/custom-sorting-python-dictionary/51471920#51471920

Answer (score 5):

It's apparent from your `print` statements that you're using Python 2.7, and yet dicts are only guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7. You can either upgrade to Python 3.7 for your exact code to work, or switch to `collections.OrderedDict` in place of dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sort_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
print(sort_x)
sort_x_dict = OrderedDict(sort_x)
print(sort_x_dict)
```

Comment: but my expected is : `{('S', 'A'): (5, 8), ('S', 'C'): (8, 14), ('S', 'B'): (11, 17)}` not `([(('S', 'A'), (5, 8)), (('S', 'C'), (8, 14)), (('S', 'B'), (11, 17))])`

Comment: `OrderedDict` subclasses `dict` so you can use it like a dict because it really a dict. It's only when you print it that its `__repr__` method would return a representation string that looks more like a list of tuples. But for all intents and purposes you can use an `OrderedDict` just like a regular dict. If you still want to use a regular dict to achieve what you want, again, you would have to upgrade to Python 3.7+.