# Python, Beautifulsoup - Extracting strings from tags based on items in list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape the site [https://www.livechart.me/winter-2019/tv](https://www.livechart.me) to get the number of episodes that have currently aired for certain shows this season. I do this by extracting the "episode-countdown" tag data which gives something like "EP11:" then a timestamp after it, and then I slice that string to only give the number (in this case the "11") and then subtract by 1 to get how many episodes have currently aired (as the timestamp is for when EP11 will air).

I have a list of the different shows I am watching this season in order to filter what shows I extract the episode-countdown strings for instead of extracting the countdown for every show airing. The big problem I am having is that the "episode-countdown" strings are not in the same order as my list of shows I am watching. For example, if my list is [show1, show2, show3, show4], I might get the "episodes-countdown" string tag in the order of show3, show4, show1, show2 if they are listed in that order on the website.

My current code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def countdown():
    html = Request('https://www.livechart.me/winter-2019/tv', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    page = urlopen(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    shows = ['Jojo no Kimyou na Bouken: Ougon no Kaze', 'Dororo', 'Mob Psycho 100 II', 'Yakusoku no Neverland']
    for tag in soup.find_all('article', attrs={'class': 'anime'}):
        if any(x in tag['data-romaji'] for x in shows):
            rlist = tag.find('div', attrs={'class': 'episode-countdown'}).text
            r2 = rlist[:rlist.index(":")][2:]
            print('{} has aired {} episodes so far'.format(tag['data-romaji'], int(r2)-1))
```

Each show listed on the website is inside of an "article" tag so for every show in the soup.find_all() statement, if the "data-romaji" (the name of the show listed on the website) matches a show in my "shows" list, then I extract the "episode-countdown" string and then slice the string to just the number as previously explained and then print to make sure I did it correctly.

If you go to the website, the order that the shows are listed are "Yakusoku no Neverland", "Mob Psycho", "Dororo", and "Jojo" which is the order that you get the episode-countdown strings in if you run the code. What I want to do is have it in order of my "shows" list so that I have a list of shows and a list of episodes aired that match each other. I want to add the episodes aired list as a column in a pandas dataframe I am currently building so having it not match the "shows" column would be a problem.

Is there a way for me to extract the "episode-countdown" string based on the order of my "shows" list instead of the order used on the website (if that makes sense)?

Comment: could you create an ordered dict? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031752/6241235

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I created an Ordered dict then sorted it based on the list of shows I had then converted the values from the ordered dict (the number of episodes) into a list that now matches my list of shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd


html = Request('https://www.livechart.me/winter-2019/tv', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

shows = ['Jojo no Kimyou na Bouken: Ougon no Kaze', 'Dororo', 'Mob Psycho 100 II', 'Yakusoku no Neverland']
master = []


for show in shows:
    for tag in soup.find_all('article', attrs={'class': 'anime'}):
    show_info = []
    if show in tag['data-romaji']:
        show_info.append(tag['data-romaji'])
        rlist = tag.find('div', attrs={'class': 'episode-countdown'}).text
        r2 = rlist[:rlist.index(":")][2:]
        show_info.append(r2)
        master.append(show_info)


 df=pd.DataFrame(master,columns=['Show','Episodes'])
 df
```

Output:

```
    Show    Episodes
  0     Jojo no Kimyou na Bouken: Ougon no Kaze     23
  1     Dororo                                      11
  2     Mob Psycho 100 II                           11
  3     Yakusoku no Neverland                       11
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly for me. I was trying to figure out how to code the double for loop like you have but couldn't get it to work so I gave up. This works better as it is shorter than the code I currently have and converts it straight to a list as opposed to converting an ordered dict into a list.