# Sort nested dictionary by variable number of keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to sort a dict by multiple keys. This is the dict I have:

```
standings = {1: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 'player': 'Jack', 'points': 15},
             2: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 0, 'player': 'Kate', 'points': 15},
             3: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 'player': 'Sawyer', 'points': 5}}
```

I want to sort it by, in this order:  `'points'`, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I could do this, I assume:

```
reversed(sorted(standings, key=lambda x: (standings[x]['points'], 
                                          standings[x][1],
                                          standings[x][2], 
                                          standings[x][3], 
                                          standings[x][4], 
                                          standings[x][5])))
```

However, the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 keys are dynamic (and could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, etc.)

So, somehow I want to make the sorting keys dynamic in `sorted()`, except for `'points'` which will always be used.

The result I want is a reversed sorted list with the keys (which are player ids from the db) from the first dict. i.e. for the given example it will be`[2, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Sorting Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031482/custom-sorting-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are looking for is [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with `range`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

standings = ...  # your dictionary of dictionaries
n = 5  # number of keys to sort on (1, 2, 3, ..., n)
# The following will collect values by 'points', 1, 2, ..., n in a tuple:
get_values = itemgetter('points', *range(1, n + 1))
result = sorted(standings, 
                key=lambda x: get_values(standings[x]), 
                reverse=True)
# [2, 1, 3]
```

---

**Explanation:**

In order to achieve the sorting by several dict keys, you could use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a function that will return a tuple of values by specified keys. So, as a simple example, if you would have this dictionary:

```
my_dict = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 'player': 'Ben'}
```

and you would want to get the values by keys `player`, `1` and `2`, you would write:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_values = itemgetter('player', 1, 2)
get_values(my_dict)
# ('Ben', 10, 20)
```

Now, as the number of the values can vary and those are actually ordered integers (1, 2, 3, ...), you could [unpack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) the given `range` to the `itemgetter`:

```
get_values = itemgetter('player', *range(1, 4))  # 'player', 1, 2, 3
get_values(my_dict)
# ('Ben', 10, 20, 30)
```

Finally, for your given example dictionary of dictionaries we get these tuples for each child dictionary and sort by them:

```
standings = {1: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 'player': 'Jack', 'points': 15},
             2: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 0, 'player': 'Kate', 'points': 15},
             3: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 'player': 'Sawyer', 'points': 5}}
max_key = 5  # you may also calculate it as a max integer key
get_values = itemgetter('points', *range(1, n + 1))
result = sorted(standings, key=lambda x: get_values(standings[x]))
# [3, 1, 2]
# or reversed:
sorted(standings, 
       key=lambda x: get_keys(standings[x]),
       reverse=True)
# [2, 1, 3]
```