# custom sorting a dictionary by values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a simple dictionary and a list which i would like to sort by the values in my dictionary.

```
data_dict = {'foo' : 'one', 'bar' : 'two', 'foobar' : 'three', 'notinsort' : 'four'}

custom_sort = ['three','one','two']
```

my own attempt has been to use a dictionary comprehension with a custom key in the sort:

```
{k:v for k,v in sorted(data_dict.items(), key=lambda i : custom_sort.index(i[1]) )}
```

which will rightly return a `ValueError: 'four' is not in list`

no problem, I can filter this out with an if-else statement within the lambda? as I still want the values to be sorted initially by my custom sort then a natural sort will do.

```
{
    k: v
    for k, v in sorted(
        data_dict.items(),
        key=lambda i: custom_sort.index(i[1])
        if [k for k in data_dict.values() if k in custom_sort] 
        else sorted(data_dict.items()),
    )
}
```

this returns the same ValueError, any variations I've tried on this will end up giving me a natural sort ignoring my custom key.

my desired output from the input above is :

```
data_dict = {'foobar' : 'three', 'foo' : 'one', 'bar' : 'two', 'notinsort' : 'four'}
```

I've had a the following questions :

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)
&
[Custom Sorting Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031482/custom-sorting-python-dictionary)

but wasn't able to come to an answer.

Comment: What do you want the output of this sort to look like, taking into account a value not in the sort list (i.e. `'four'`)? Should it be in the sorted output? If so, at the end? At the start?

Comment: @PyPingu would like to be naturally sorted after my own custom sort (as per my example), but if you could show both that would be very interesting - however understand if its not within the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by naturally sorted? Do you mean deafult output if you just called `sorted(dict.items())`? Because if so then I think yatu's answer is your solution

Comment: Apologies for my use of bad language, by natural I meant the default sort of the `sorted` method yes it does, thanks @PyPingu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could instead define a dictionary beforehand for the lookups (reducing the complexity to that of sorting, i.e `O(n log n)`, since dictionary look-ups are `O(1)` ). This works for python 3.6> where dictionarie's order is mantained:

```
d = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(custom_sort)}
# {'three': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}
dict(sorted(data_dict.items(), key=lambda x: d.get(x[1], float('inf'))))
# {'foobar': 'three', 'foo': 'one', 'bar': 'two', 'notinsort': 'four'}
```

Comment: Might also point out the benefit of the dictionary over repeatedly calling `index`

Comment: Yup OP does use that approach, will do @tobias