# How to insert numbers at the end

Tags: python, sorting

I have this code that sorts characters in a string and counts the number of times it's repeated.

```
def char_repetition(str):
    
    reps = dict()
    word = [character.lower() for character in str.split()]
    word.sort()
    
    for x in word:
        if x in reps:
            reps[x] += 1
        else:
            reps[x] = 1

    return reps


for x in char_repetition(str):
    print (x,char_repetition(str)[x])
```

So an input of `'1 2 3 2 1 a b c b a'` would yield:

> 1   2
>  2   2
>  3   1
> a   2
>  b   2
>  c   1

The problem is that I want the numbers to appear at the end of the output  like that:

> a   2
>  b   2
>  c   1
> 1   2
>  2   2
>  3   1

Comment: You should sort the dictionary with a custom comperator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031482/custom-sorting-python-dictionary

Comment: Use e.g.`word.sort(key=lambda i: (i.isdigit(), i))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    word = [character.lower() for character in str.split()]
    word.sort()
```

to

```
    digits = []
    chars = []
    for c in sorted(st.split()):
        if c.isdigit():
            digits.append(c)
        else:
            chars.append(c.lower())
    word = chars + digits
```

---

From ekhumoro  in the comments, you can use a custom key to sort the list:

From:

```
    word = [character.lower() for character in str.split()]
    word.sort()
```

to:

```
    word = [character.lower() for character in str.split()]
    word.sort(key=lambda i: (1, int(i)) if i.isdigit() else (0, i))
```

Comment: PS: if the the list contains multi-digit numbers, it would be better to do: `word.sort(key=lambda i: (1, int(i)) if i.isdigit() else (0, i))`.