# Sort dictionary by key length. Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort my dictionary be length of keys (first- keys with the biggest length, in the end - with the smallest)

For example:

```
dictionary = {"aa" : 1, "aaaaaaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "a": 4}
```

as a result after sorting must be:

```
{"aaaaaaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "aa" : 1, "a": 4}
```

Comment: Another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753758/dictionary-sorting-by-key-length)

Comment: the key thing to note however, is that dictionaries inherently are unordered! check out OrderedDict if you specifically need it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

Dictionaries are considered unordered, but newer versions of Python (3.6+) remember the insertion order, so you can do:

```
d = {"aa" : 1, "aaaaaaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "a": 4}

new_d = {}
for k in sorted(d, key=len, reverse=True):
    new_d[k] = d[k]

print(new_d)
# {'aaaaaaa': 2, 'aaa': 3, 'aa': 1, 'a': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries can't be "sorted" in the traditional way because they are an unordered key-value storage. You probabilaly want to use a multidimensional list.

```
>>> d = [["aa", 1], ["aaaaaaa", 2], ["aaa", 3], ["a", 4]]
>>> d
[['aa', 1], ['aaaaaaa', 2], ['aaa', 3], ['a', 4]]
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda l: len(l[0]), reverse=True)
[['aaaaaaa', 2], ['aaa', 3], ['aa', 1], ['a', 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {"aa" : 1, "aaaaaaa": 2, "aaa" : 3, "a": 4}
new_dic={}
k = list(dic.items())
k.sort(key=lambda x:len(x[0]),reverse=True)

for i in k :
    new_dic.update({i[0]:i[1]})

print(new_dic)
```