# from collections import OrderedDict and python version

Tags: python

I am working with some python code given to me, and it fails on my system.  Specifically on the statement of `from collections import OrderedDict` having a capital O and capital D.
But if I change the statement to be `import ordereddict` it does not fail.
And if I try `import OrderedDict` it fails with a not found error.

My version of python is 2.6.9 per the SuSE SLES SDK 11.4.
The python I am trying to execute I believe was written for an earlier 2.6.x version of python.

Is this problem I am experiencing a direct result of the python version?
Does anyone have any suggestions how to properly fix this problem?
Is there a difference between `OrderedDict` and `ordereddict` and whether or not it comes from `collections`?

Comment: `OrderedDict` [appeared](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in version 2.7.

Comment: Related: [OrderedDict for older versions of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617078/ordereddict-for-older-versions-of-python)

Comment: Read the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=Equivalent#collections.OrderedDict) which tells you in what version it was introduced as well as where to find an **Equivalent OrderedDict recipe** for older versions.

Comment: it seems i am missing some more python libraries, no surprise not the first time with SLES.

Answer (score 2):

The lower case one is for older python versions that has to be installed separately. Related question: [OrderedDict for older versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617078/ordereddict-for-older-versions-of-python)

Comment: so SLES 11.4 has lower case ordereddict with python 2.6.9 but does not have the newer OrderedDict.

Comment: Can someone point me to the proper website for manually downloading this OrderedDict python package?

Comment: going to try ordereddict1.1.tar.gz authored by  Raymond Hettinger from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict.  Description is:  drop-in substitute for Py2.7's new collections.**OrderedDict** that works in Python 2.4-2.6

Comment: so the ordereddict1.1.tar.gz does not provide the capital OrderedDict functionality.  It seems i need the python 2.7 version of `collections`  ?