# Cannot install ordereddict to specific Python version on Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-18.04, ordereddict

I am trying to install the ordereddict module to my Python 2.7 setup as I get an error saying this is missing when I attempt to execute code. When I try `sudo pip install ordereddict` this seems to install it to my Python 3.6 build...I was off the impression that `sudo pip3 install ordereddict` should install to 3.6.

I am therefore trying the following from the PYPI page:

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install ordereddict
```

Unfortunately though this is throwing up the following errors when executed:

```
gdogg371@ubuntu:~$ sudo python2.7 -m pip install ordereddict
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "/home/gdogg371/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 8, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [Perhaps this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6) :)

Comment: `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OrderedDict for older versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1617078/608639). The Q&A provides the details of the versions of Python that support `OrderedDict`, how to install it on older versions of Python, and how to write a program that uses `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python2.7 `OrderedDict` is a built-in structure.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

P.S. in python 3.6 dicts are already ordered so you don't need it.