# Print dict iteration elements as it is read(declared)

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6, iteritems

I am reading a dictionary in python2.6 as below 
I know Python3.6 will read the dictionary in the same order it is declared, but i need to achieve this in Python2.6 (OrderedDict is also not available in Python2.6)

```
numbermap = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

>>> for k, v in numbermap.iteritems():
...    print(k,v)
...
('four', 4)
('three', 3)
('five', 5)
('two', 2)
('one', 1)
```

I want the output to be

```
('one',1)
('two', 2)
('three', 3)
('four', 4)
('five', 5)
```

I need to write as I read the dictionary. Any ideas to achieve this in Python 2.6?

Comment: Python dictionaries aren't ordered data structures.

Comment: Any way to sorted as i read them?

Comment: Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the collections module if applicable in 2.6 - do you know about https://pythonclock.org/ ? Time to update. If you switch to 3.6 CPython or AnyPythong 3.7 you get insert order guranteed for nothing

Comment: Just saw: OrderedDict is not available for 2.6 - if you want them as you printed them, the only way to achieve it is to sort by value - but thats less then ideal because it does not reflect your insert order at all ... just put a `"ninetynine":99` in the first place ... its only by the values choosen that this fits.

Comment: unfortunately, i have to do it in Python2.6.6, Is there anyway because OrderedDict is not available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want an ordered dictionary.  If you can use Python 2.7, look up `collections.OrderedDict`:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

If you have to stick with 2.6, there are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617087/3061818 (but you should probably head over to [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared))

Comment: The docs say `New in version 2.7` and the question is tagged with `python-2.6`.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't see that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many practices available for the sorting dictionary. You can check below examples.

First example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> numbermap = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
>>> sorted_maps = sorted(numbermap.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> print(sorted_maps)
[('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5)]
```

Second example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> sorted_maps = collections.OrderedDict(numbermap)
>>> print(sorted_maps)
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5)])
```

Comment: 2.7 for OrderedDict - not in 2.6 - and your first approach only works for _this_ set of values - not for f.e. `{'nine':9, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}`

Answer (score -1):

1 reverse the key value,

2 sort the new key which is the value

my solution is to sort the keys

sounds like cheating, but works:

first call something to reverse dict

```
for i in sort(numbermap.keys()):
  print(i,numbermap[i])
```

Comment: This won't work, because the order of keys is not the order the OP wants.

Comment: if you sort the key alphabetically - it wont. `four` before `one` just to name one

Comment: just an idea, u can reverse the key value and order the new key which is the current value